# How to subscribe on localStorage but not on sessionStorage events

Tags: javascript, events, local-storage

As far as I understand:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event){
       ...
}, false);
```

is subscription on both localStorage and sessionStorage events.
Can I subscribe on localStorage events only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think you can, as you say `storage` is [fired on the window when any storage item changes](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-event). You just have to check the `storageArea` property of the event when you receive it, and ignore the ones from session storage. E.g.:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event){
    if (event.storageArea === localStorage) {
        // It's local storage
    }
}, false);
```